# SSRS print x pages with same design but different page #

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

My company wants to print pallet tags for their warehouses.  The design of each pallet tag will be the same except the pallet number is different on the footer.  How can I pass in an integer parameter specifying the number of pallets and have that many pages print with the footer saying "Pallet 1 of X" ... "Pallet 2 of X" ... etc?  This is a report that integrates with MS Dynamics AX so some solutions may not be possible, but I will hear them all.

Comment: Are you using a separate report table as data source? If yes, you could add as many records to the table as you want pages and do a page break after each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FH-Inway had it right.  Although very simplistic and redundant, creating multiple records all with the same values seemed to be the only way to get multiple pages to print.